# z3 Solver and solve give different results

Tags: z3, z3py

I have been experimenting with z3 (version '4.8.7' obtained through pip3) and found this (apparent) discrepancy.

```
t, s0, s, u, a, v = Reals('t s0 s u a v')
equations = [v == u + a*t, s == s0 + u*t + a*t**2/2,
             v**2 - u**2 == 2*a*s]
problem = [t == 10, s0 == 0, u == 0, a == 9.81]
solve(equations+problem)
```

This gives the correct output for s:

[a = 981/100, u = 0, s0 = 0, t = 10, s = 981/2, v = 981/10]

But when I use the Solver, the result is different:

```
solver = Solver()
solver.check(equations+problem)
solver.model()
```

This gives a wrong output for s, though it gets v right.

[t = 10, u = 0, s0 = 0, s = 0, a = 981/100, v = 981/10]

s should be (1/2) * (981/100) * 100 which is the result in solve.

Am I missing something obvious in z3's Solver or is this a bug? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the argument to `solver.check` are extra assumptions the solver can make as it solves the constraints, not the actual constraints to check. See the documentation here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html#l06628

The correct call would be:

```py
solver = Solver()
solver.add(equations+problem)
print solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

that is, you `add` the constraints, and then call `check` with no arguments. This would match what `solve` does. The argument to `check` are used if you want to check validity under some extra assumptions only.